# How do I make Example.vue update in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components, laravel-5.4

I just read the answers to this question and wasn't able to get a good response.

[Laravel Example.vue not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241106/laravel-example-vue-not-updating)

I also posted this question trying to figure it out on my own but to no avail.

[how do I load a Vue component in Laravel 5.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311010/how-do-i-load-a-vue-component-in-laravel-5-4)

As another attempt, I just did a new reinstall of Laravel, and while I am able to get the default Example.vue component to load multiple times in a single view, I am still unable to change the contents of the component. Funnier thing is that when I run npm install and then npm run dev, the component ceases to even show up anymore.

This is really frustrating because Laravel ships with Vue.js yet I am unable to utilize it. Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I load a Vue component in Laravel 5.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311010/how-do-i-load-a-vue-component-in-laravel-5-4)

Comment: You should not create a new question for the same thing. Keep updating your original question with details...

Comment: the answer below should solve your problem

Comment: Yes it looks very similar to [yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43311194/1575353)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the node dependencies and then compile them.

1. Install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)
2. From your projects root run `npm install`
3. From your projects root run `npm run dev`

Your browser may also be showing the cached version. Chrome has a setting that you can have the cache disabled while the inspector is open.

You can also check it by opening your project in other browsers.

If when running `npm run dev` dies without any message of any kind you can delete your node_modules folder then run `npm install` and then compile your assets again.

You may also need to clear and rebuild a few other caches with commands:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
```

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/frontend

Answer (score 0):

Double check and make sure you're in the resources directory and not public. If you're in the correct directory try `npm install` then `npm run watch`