# I can't test simple vue example component on Laravel 5.4

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.4

I have a fresh laravel 5.4 installation, i run `npm install` and then proceed to test the example vue component, but nothing happens.

On my project's directory I run `npm run dev` and It compiles just fine. Then I execute `php artisan serve` and all I see is a blank page.

Here's my view, which is the only code I wrote:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
        <example></example>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is that ok? am I missing something?

On my package.json, on devDepentencies, among other stuff I have: `"vue": "^2.1.10"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you didn't run `php artisan make:auth` so laravel didn't set the javascript object "Laravel" with "csrfToken" property.

In resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js, try to comment this line :

`window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken;`

And recompile with `npm run dev`.

Comment: This solved it, thanks.

If you or someone could share their quick opinion on php artisan make:auth; I know it's for quickly setting up the user authentication for new projects, but the application I'm gonna create is for a company that needs another sistem. The users will log in to my project using their credentials from their main database, however I will create a users table (in my projects db) copying their username and a couple of more fields, but wont allow them to edit that info. The can only edit a new field (an avatar).

Should i use php artisan make:auth or handle this manually?

Comment: The laravel `make:auth` authentification is easily editable to match with the developer needs. However, in your case, you can use your own authentification system for a better understanding and a more scalable code.